# Download Tiktok video Using a Java class in android studio

Tags: download, tiktok

I created a code snippet which should download tiktok videos but unfortunately it doesn't, it just downloads the Html File of the tiktok website's page with the name of a video i.e tiktok_video.mp4
when i try to Play it using a videoPlayer the videoPlayer shows an error
But when i open it using a text reader it shows the whole html code of the page

I created a java class named
**DownloadTask.javva**
In my app

Here's the Code

```
package com.zk.tiktokstudio;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import android.os.Environment;

import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.io.InputStream;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

import java.net.URL;

public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    private static final String TAG = "DownloadTask";

    @Override

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String videoUrl = urls[0];

        String fileName = "tiktok_video.mp4";

        try {

            URL url = new URL(videoUrl);

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.connect();

            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), fileName);

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int len;

            long total = 0;

            while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {

                total += len;

                publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));

                fos.write(buffer, 0, len);

            }

            fos.close();

            is.close();

            return outputFile.getAbsolutePath();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e(TAG, "Error downloading file: " + e.getMessage());

        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);

        // Update progress bar or UI element here

    }

    @Override

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);

        // File download complete, perform any necessary operations here

    }


}
```

To use this DownloadTask class
I simply create an instance of it and execute it by passing the TikTok video URL as a parameter.

```
String videoUrl = "https://www.tiktok.com/@username/video/1234567890";

DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

downloadTask.execute(videoUrl);
```

How can I download the video instead of html file with the name of a video?